# How does the styleguide generate template work?

Tags: material-design-lite

I can't figure out how this Sass block get replaced by the gulp script?

https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/master/src/_variables.scss#L104-L110

```
@if $styleguide-generate-template == true {
  $color-primary: '$color-primary';
  $color-primary-dark: '$color-primary-dark';
  $color-accent: '$color-accent';
  $color-primary-contrast: '$color-primary-contrast';
  $color-accent-contrast: '$color-accent-contrast';
}
```

https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/master/gulpfile.babel.js#L142

For example how can I create my own color template without messing up the mdl sccs by using the gulp file?

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about the styleguide block at all. That is for generating the file used for custom generation on the frontend of the customizer provided.

To make your own color template, simply define the variables in this block in your scss before importing `material-design-lite.scss`.

Comment: Ok that makes sence, but still the `the styleguide block` is a total mystery where it gets it variables set in the gulpfile. I understand I don't need to ever worry about it but I want to understand the gulp process of it :)

Comment: That has nothing to do with the gulp process. This is all Sass only. This block is saying to put strings in place of the values when generating the customizer file. This allows easy replacement in JS for the customizer

Comment: Can you give me the github url of the part in the js code please where customizer is replacing the code?

Comment: https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/master/docs/_assets/customizer.js#L425

Comment: Thank you :) Can you include it in your answer please, then I can accept it

Comment: I don't see the point in including it in the answer, since the answer already answers your exact question. All this comment discussion is something unrelated to the primary question.

Comment: Because the title of my question is related to it? And it's very valuable information because I couldn't figure it out myself. How the style guid template worked.

Comment: I still don't get how to put my own branding colors on that variables. For example, mi primary dark is #304654 but MDL seems to work with RGBs. How is the format to replace that color in _variables.scss? Or did I have to add my own template RGB colors on customizer.js before build? Thanks.

Comment: So `$color-primary-dark: rgb(48,70,84) !default;`  is OK as syntax?